# Error 9 on a DataBodyRange selection of a previously filtered sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the following code to

1. select all visible cells in 1 column of a previously filtered sheet (Database) to then
2. apply validation to all those visible cells, from 1 dynamic column kept in a separate sheet (SKU Check). At the line: `Set tbl_5 = Activesheet.......` the vba returns `error 9, subscript out of range`. The Database sheet had already been filtered before this module is reached.

**Any idea if its refferencing? the Database sheet is table data, not sure if that alters anything...**

Code:

```
Sub VALIDATION_c()

  Dim tbl_5 As ListObject
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim PH5Rng As Range
  Dim Val5 As Range
  Dim WS As Workbook

  Sheets("Database").Select
  Set tbl_5 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SKU Check").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Select
  Set rng = tbl_5.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  Set Val5 = Sheets("SKU Check").Range("G1:G20")
  Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SKU CHECK")

  For Each tbl_5 In rng.Areas

    With tbl_5.Validation
    .Delete 'delete previous validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:="='" & WS.Name & "'!" & Val5.Address
    End With
  Next

  MsgBox ("DONE VALIDATION")

End Sub
```

Comment: @DavidZeeman, this is built off something you previously answered

Comment: @davidZemens, appologies

Comment: If tbl_5 is supposed to be a ListObject (per dim) then it should be set to be a ListObject and not the Column of a ListObject and certainly not the DataBodyRange. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hey Ralph, i need to select the DataBodyRange of that specific Column. The DataBody Rnage IS a list object

Comment: Did you try `Set tbl_5 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SKU Check")`?

Comment: I did try that Ralph, :/

Comment: I have a hard time believing that because in my Excel it is not allowed to name a ListObject "SKU Check". This is due to the fact that there is a space in between. But the names for ListObjects cannot contain spaces. Furthermore, it seems confusing that you have a ListObject by the name "SKU Check" and also a sheet by the name "SKU Check".

Comment: Also, you might want to change `Sheets("Sheet1").Select` to `Sheets("Sheet1").Activate` and if WS is supposed to be a Workbook (per dim) then you should set WS to `Set WS = ThisWorkbook` and not a sheet within that workbook.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

1. Like @Ralph pointed out in the comments, it is not possible to have a table called "SKU Check"

   - ListObjects names cannot contain a space
   - This is what causes your "Error 9: Subscript out of range"
2. tbl_5 is defined: `Dim tbl_5 As ListObject`

   - You attempt to assign a DataBodyRange to this ListObjects. As the type names imply:

     - A "ListObject" is an object
     - A "DataBodyRange" is a Range object
     - This will generate an error
3. You are actually assigning the result of the .Select action

   - .Select returns a Variant that contains True or False (the result of the action)
4. WS is defined as `Dim WS As Workbook`

   - You attempt to assign a Worksheet object to it and it will generate another error

---

To fix your code, providing that on Worksheets("Database") you have a table called "SKUCheck":

```
Option Explicit

Sub VALIDATION_c()

    Dim ws1     As Worksheet
    Dim ws2     As Worksheet
    Dim tbl     As ListObject
    Dim col1    As Range
    Dim col2    As Range

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Database")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("SKU Check")
    Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects("SKUCheck")

    Set col1 = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set col2 = ws2.Range("G1:G20")

    With col1.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Formula1:="='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & col2.Address
    End With

    MsgBox ("DONE VALIDATION")
End Sub
```