# List Object combined with cell validation on a previously filtered cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the following code to

1. select all visible cells in 1 column of a previously filtered sheet (Database) to then
2. apply validation to all those visible cells, from 1 dynamic column kept in a separate sheet (SKU Check). At the line: Set tbl_5 = Activesheet....... the vba returns error 9, subscript out of range. The Database sheet had already been filtered before this module is reached.

Currently I am getting error, as Object Required for the Set tbl_5 value

Code:

```
Sub VALIDATION_c()

Dim tbl_5 As ListObject
Dim rng As Range
Dim PH5Rng As Range
Dim Val5 As Range
Dim WS As Workbook

Sheets("Database").Select
Set tbl_5 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SKU Check").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Select
Set rng = tbl_5.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set Val5 = Sheets("SKU Check").Range("G1:G20")
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SKU CHECK")

 For Each tbl_5 In rng.Areas

With tbl_5.Validation
.Delete 'delete previous validation
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:="='" & WS.Name & "'!" & Val5.Address
End With
Next

MsgBox ("DONE VALIDATION")

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplication of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185455/error-9-on-a-databodyrange-selection-of-a-previously-filtered-sheet#comment50381309_31185455

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as in this question: [Error 9 on a DataBodyRange selection of a previously filtered sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185455/error-9-on-a-databodyrange-selection-of-a-previously-filtered-sheet/31221270#31221270)

There are several issues in your code:

1. It is not possible to have a table called "SKU Check"

   - ListObjects names cannot contain a space
   - This is what causes your "Error 9: Subscript out of range"
2. tbl_5 is defined: `Dim tbl_5 As ListObject`

   - You attempt to assign a DataBodyRange to this ListObjects. As the type names imply:

     - A "ListObject" is an object
     - A "DataBodyRange" is a Range object
     - This will generate an error
3. You are actually assigning the result of the .Select action

   - .Select returns a Variant that contains True or False (the result of the action)
4. WS is defined as `Dim WS As Workbook`

   - You attempt to assign a Worksheet object to it and it will generate another error

---

To fix your code, providing that on Worksheets("Database") you have a table called "SKUCheck":

```
Option Explicit

Sub VALIDATION_c()

    Dim ws1     As Worksheet
    Dim ws2     As Worksheet
    Dim tbl     As ListObject
    Dim col1    As Range
    Dim col2    As Range

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Database")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("SKU Check")
    Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects("SKUCheck")

    Set col1 = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set col2 = ws2.Range("G1:G20")

    With col1.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Formula1:="='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & col2.Address
    End With

    MsgBox ("DONE VALIDATION")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

via email please
Your code no work
Sub VALIDATION_c()

```
Dim ws1     As Worksheet
Dim ws2     As Worksheet
Dim tbl     As ListObject
Dim col1    As Range
Dim col2    As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("C8.-INSUMOS")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("C13.- PU")
Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects("TABLAINSUDINAMIC")

Set col1 = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set col2 = ws2.Range("A:A")

With col1.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Formula1:="='" & ws2.Name & "'!" & col2.Address
End With
```

End Sub